# trying to InvokeMember a submit button with c#

Tags: javascript, c#, webbrowser-control, invokemember

1. This is the code of the website :

   ```
   function checkSubmit(e)
   {
      if(e && e.keyCode == 13)
      {
         document.frmLogin.submit();
      }
   }
   <div class="enterButton" onclick="document.frmLogin.submit()">Sign in</div>
   ```
2. This is what I tried in c# :

   ```
   HtmlElementCollection elc1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
   foreach (HtmlElement element in elc1)
   {
       if (element.GetAttribute("InnerHtml").Equals("<DIV onclick=document.frmLogin.submit() class=enterButton>Sign in</DIV>"))
       {
           element.InvokeMember("submit()");
       }
   }
   ```
3. The `foreach` is working and the `if` statement is working when it gets to the `InvokeMember` nothing happens.

Comment: How'd you get c# running in the browser?

Comment: @Will OP tries to call a javascript function in WebBrowser control in c# which is possible....

Comment: I am running VS13 windows form with webbrowser controler.....

Comment: Note that your title refers to a "submit button", which is generally the name for HTML like `<input type="submit"/>`, but your code shows a `div`, which is not a button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble I just was at the wrong element:

```
if (element.GetAttribute("InnerHtml").Equals("Sign in"))
{
element.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

now it works....

Answer (score -1):

Try the Invoke member method without the brackets.

```
 element.InvokeMember("submit");
```

Comment: Round brackets or *parentheses* :)

Comment: The ones I removed in the answer above... :)

Comment: Don't you want to invoke `"click"`, since the `element` is a `div`?